# Is this OOP conversion possible

Tags: c#, oop

I am working on an utilitity class to build up some common functions.

One of the function tries to customized a window form attributes. 
The function accept a parameter, which should be a window form reference variable, then it customize its layout.

The problem is that window forms are different objects type, e.g. Form1, Form2, ...etc
Therefore, I cannot figure what object type should I used in the function.
e.g. public static void SetFormAttributes(ref ??? targetForm)

The code are as follows:

```
    void btn_show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pnl_ShowForms.Controls.Clear();
        int tag = Convert.ToInt32( (sender as Button).Tag);
        switch (tag)
        {
            case 1:
                Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
                Utilities.SetFormAttributes(ref frm1);
                this.pnl_ShowForms.Controls.Add(frm1);
                frm1.Show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
                Utilities.SetFormAttributes(ref frm2);                
                this.pnl_ShowForms.Controls.Add(frm2);
                frm2.Show();
                break;
            case 3:
                Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
                Utilities.SetFormAttributes(ref frm3);
                this.pnl_ShowForms.Controls.Add(frm3);
                frm3.Show();
                break;
        }
    }


namespace WFA_ShowFormsInPanel
{
public static class Utilities
{
    public static void SetFormAttributes(ref ??? targetForm)
    {

        {
            targetForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            targetForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            targetForm.TopLevel = false;
        }      
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: why ref? (adding padding to meet minimum comment size requirements)

Comment: I have tested the code suggested and it works.
However, why ref is not necessary? I am new to OOP, I thought that I have to pass by ref if I want to changed the original object. Any hits or links explaining this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

All your forms inherit from the base [`Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, so use this type in `SetFormAttributes`.

As a side note, as `Form` is an object (so a *reference* type), using `ref` to pass it as parameter is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to

```
   public static class Utilities
{
    public static void SetFormAttributes(Form targetForm)
    {

        {
            targetForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            targetForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            targetForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            targetForm.TopLevel = false;
        }      
      }
}
```

Since all Windows forms will inherit from `Form`.